# Concept of schema in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database-schema

Is there a suggested way to use "schemas" in mysql? For example, if I have one database called `events` and then I want to have two environments `dev` and `prod`, what might be a way to do that? Currently I add a table prefix, but it seems a a bit hack-ish:

[image]

Comment: No. Postgres has these, MySQL does not.

Comment: Use two databases with the same set of tables in each.

Comment: @tadman right I mean, "Since mysql doesn't have this feature...how can this concept be achieved in it?"

Comment: The closest thing in MySQL is other databases, as these act as quasi-schemas, especially since you can involve them in queries. This is what Barmar suggests here. If you need true schemas the answer is "use Postgres".

Comment: @tadman: actually, MySQL doesn't really have "databases" - what they call a "database" is in fact a schema.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Effectively, yes. MySQL 3 made a number of bizarre decisions that persist to this day.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name in that sense, what's the difference between a "database" and a "schema"? They are often used interchangeably (especially in mysql's documentation).

Comment: @carl.hiass: a database (called "catalog" in the SQL standard) can contain multiple schemas. They represent nested namespaces with database (catalog) being the top level, schema being the second level. So "real objects" like tables are always created inside a schema. And a schema is created inside a database (catalog)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you create a separate database for that, because MySQL does not have the concept of `schema` like e.g. PostgreSQL does.

You create one database for production e.g. prod_database with the table names event and event_type. and one database for dev e.g. dev_database, with the same table names event and event_type. As you always want to have the same table names in different environments.

You could (and should) even use the same database name, if you host the database on different servers. Which for production and development/staging would also make sense e.g. to test server version updates on one setup without affecting production.